# Доступ к панели управления сайту по HTTP: безопасно ли это?

Tags: хостинг

Приобрёл у хостинг-провайдера место для сайта. Вдруг выяснилось, что панель управления сайтом (DirectAdmin) доступна только по HTTP и не доступна по HTTPS.  При этом адрес панели управления имеет вид [http://ip-адрес:порт](http://ip-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81:%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82). Браузер периодически выдаёт предупреждение, что пароль может быть скомпрометирован.

Подскажите пожалуйста насколько опасно пользоваться такой панелью управления? Есть ли смысл поискать другой хостинг, если не удасться подключиться к этой панели управления по HTTPS?

Насколько я понимаю, при использовании HTTP возможна атака man-in-the-middle и человек сидящий между мной и хостингом может получить полный контроль над моим сайтом. Или это не так?

Answer (score 0):

Сомневаешься? Меняй хостинг, а то будешь все время об этом думать) Я бы сменил. Не зря же http считается не безопасным. Они могут говорить, что защита и на этом протоколе у них высочайшая, но сомнения... Будешь постоянно об этом думать) И да. По http можно перехватить пароли.